# Sort Pandas DataFrame using multi-criteria weighting

Tags: python, pandas

**Overview**

For the following Pandas DataFrame I can sort the data using `sort_values` (I used "Clust Length" here) but this will not allow me to sort using a multi-criteria decision-making approach.  I tried adding a list to `sort_values` with `by=[col1,col2]` etc but one column is ultimately sorting the DataFrame unless the first column has a duplicate value.

**Desired output**

For all columns a higher value is preferred.  Is there a simple way to sort based on an even mix of all the columns?  Could the data be normalised and weighted?

For example,

- row 1 `Clust Max Date` value of `2020-11-30` > row 0 `2018-09-29`
- row 1 `Clust Bounce` value of `404.40` > row 0 `268.30`

but row 0 is first because of the current sorting method.  Ideally row 1 would be higher than row 0 as per this truncated df showing only two rows as an example.

(Short example showing sorted rows using desired approach)

[image]

(Existing DataFrame for reference.)
[image]

**Data to recreate the DataFrame is below**

```
df.to_dict()

{'Clust Length': {0: 9,
  1: 8,
  2: 8,
  3: 7,
  4: 6,
  5: 6,
  6: 5,
  7: 2,
  8: 5,
  9: 1},
 'Clust Bounce Median': {0: 268.2999999999991,
  1: 404.4000000000003,
  2: 174.15000000000015,
  3: 221.79999999999978,
  4: 148.59999999999985,
  5: 191.39999999999935,
  6: 35.49999999999942,
  7: 59.19999999999925,
  8: 242.9999999999999,
  9: 84.59999999999911},
 'Clust Min Date': {0: '2008-12-31 00:00:00+00:00',
  1: '2008-09-29 23:00:00+00:00',
  2: '2008-03-30 23:00:00+00:00',
  3: '2007-09-29 23:00:00+00:00',
  4: '2010-02-28 00:00:00+00:00',
  5: '2004-08-30 23:00:00+00:00',
  6: '2003-10-31 00:00:00+00:00',
  7: '2016-02-29 00:00:00+00:00',
  8: '2015-02-28 00:00:00+00:00',
  9: '2010-02-28 00:00:00+00:00'},
 'Clust Max Date': {0: '2018-09-29 23:00:00+00:00',
  1: '2020-11-30 00:00:00+00:00',
  2: '2012-11-30 00:00:00+00:00',
  3: '2013-04-29 23:00:00+00:00',
  4: '2012-10-31 00:00:00+00:00',
  5: '2019-10-31 00:00:00+00:00',
  6: '2020-08-30 23:00:00+00:00',
  7: '2020-10-31 00:00:00+00:00',
  8: '2018-05-30 23:00:00+00:00',
  9: '2013-11-30 00:00:00+00:00'}}
```

Comment: You are saying that *for all columns a higher value is preferred*, which is okay. But then you are saying that you would like the row with the higher "Cluster Bounce Median" to be higher than the row with the lower Cluster Bounce Median, but that specific row has a lower (!) Cluster Length. This makes me think that you need to specify which columns carry more weight in terms of being sorted first by their higher value, otherwise I don't see any clear solution to your problem. Unless I am not getting you correctly. Could you perhaps add your full desired output and not just the first 2 rows?

Comment: I'm not really clear of what this "even mix" might be? Can you share the desired output for the whole sample dataset? You want to sort by all columns, preferring the ones with bigger number of greater columns?

Comment: Yes sort by all columns preferring the ones with bigger numbers  @GrzegorzSkibinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank each column separately, sum ranks row-wise and order descending:

```py
df['order'] = df.rank().sum(axis=1)
df.sort_values('order', inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is this an even mix of all the columns with each one affecting the ranking as much as others? i.e. are "Cluster Length" and "Cluster Bounce Median" having the same effect on ranking with this approach?  As "Cluster Length" is a smaller number than the on one in "Cluster Bounce Median" could they be normalised first?   The approach here seems close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, exactly - every column has even weight

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want, here it is:

```
    for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].sort_values(ascending=False).to_list()
df
   Clust Length  Clust Bounce Median             Clust Min Date             Clust Max Date
0             9               404.40  2016-02-29 00:00:00+00:00  2020-11-30 00:00:00+00:00
1             8               268.30  2015-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  2020-10-31 00:00:00+00:00
2             8               243.00  2010-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  2020-08-30 23:00:00+00:00
3             7               221.80  2010-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  2019-10-31 00:00:00+00:00
4             6               191.40  2008-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  2018-09-29 23:00:00+00:00
5             6               174.15  2008-09-29 23:00:00+00:00  2018-05-30 23:00:00+00:00
6             5               148.60  2008-03-30 23:00:00+00:00  2013-11-30 00:00:00+00:00
7             5                84.60  2007-09-29 23:00:00+00:00  2013-04-29 23:00:00+00:00
8             2                59.20  2004-08-30 23:00:00+00:00  2012-11-30 00:00:00+00:00
9             1                35.50  2003-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  2012-10-31 00:00:00+00:00
```

But remember, if you sort like this, the data integrity between the columns will be lost.

Comment: This isn't the desired output as the data integrity should not be lost.  Each row should retain its data.